# Use explode in a smarter way

Tags: php, explode

I have the following string:

```
$string = "This is my string, that I would like to explode. But not\, this last part";
```

I want to `explode(',', $string)` the string, but `explode()` should not explode when there is a `\` in front of the comma.

Wanted result:

```
array(2) {
  [0] => This is my string
  [1] => that I would like to explode. But not , this last part
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `preg_split()`:

```
$result = preg_split('/(?<!\\\),/', $string);

print_r($result);
```

`(?<!\\\\)` is a lookbehind.  So a `,` not preceded by a `\`. Using `\\\` is needed to represent a single `\` since it's an escape character.

Comment: thanks it works! But it shows the `\\`. Can you show me how to get rid of it?

Comment: I testes it but I only want to get rid of the slashs that are(/were) followed by a comma..